# osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz and Error #2032

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm totally new to FLASH , but I have to use a precompiled component in my application. For some reason that component doesn't work for some clients. Details are described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868837/error-2032-when-loading-flash-component

Now, after painstaking investigation with one concerned client it turned out that my Flash component

```
https://domain.com/appname/swf/component_name.swf
```

is making a call to

```
https://domain.com/appname/swf/osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz
```

and apparently that call is causing #2032 error. What is more, there is no sign of **osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz** on the server. Therefore there're a few questions I have:

- why flash component is calling for that swz file
- why flash component fails to work only for minute number of clients, and what can cause that issue
- how to get rid of that error

Thanks a latte,
Paweł

Comment: I recall having this issue once when I had installed a 'release' version of everything on the server; then later overwrote the component_name.swf with a debug version.  (I think that's what happened.)

Comment: I'm using the same version of component on live server for about 6months. Everything worked fine for several months until now... I don't have to much background in Flash, but is there the osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz should be installed on client's PC along with Flash Player?

Comment: I'm no expert either but I just looked on one of my servers... the file osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz is on there in the same directory as my component.  I'd bet most people have it cached or included somehow in their flash install.  In any event, I think I got the file from Flash Builder's release building function (or whatever that is called.)